# How to run a function inside a child stateful widget from parent widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run a function(with arguments) **inside two-levels down StateFul widget**, by clicking a **button** in the parent of the parent of that child(*after having all widgets built, so not inside the constructor*). just like in the image below:
[image: two level of widgets speaks to each others]

More details is that I created a Carousal which has Cards inside, [published here](https://pub.dev/packages/selectable_carousel).

I created it with StreamBuilder in mind(this was the only use case scenario that I used it for so far), so once the stream send an update, the builder re-create the whole Carousal, so I can pass the SELECTED_CARD_ID to it.

**But now I need to trigger the selection of the carousal's Cards programmatically,** or in another word no need for two construction based on the snapshot's data like this:

```dart
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: userProfileBloc.userFaviourateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return SelectableCarousal(
            selectedId: snapshot.data.toInt(),
            onTap: //Update the stream
            //some props...,
          );
        } else {
          return SelectableCarousalLoading(
            selectedId: null,
            onTap: //Update the stream
            //some props...,
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

**But instead, I'm trying to have something like this so I can use it for others use cases:**

```dart
Widget myCarousal =  SelectableCarousal(
    selectedId: null,
    onTap: //Update the stream
    //some props...,
);
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: userProfileBloc.userFaviourateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        // Then when data ready I can update 
        // the selection by calling two-level down function
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          myCarousal.selectById(3);
        }

        // Build same carousal in all cases.
        return myCarousal;
      },
    );
```

so this led me to my original question "**How to run a function(with arguments) inside two-levels down StateFul widget?**".

I appreciate any help. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve that challenge using the **BLoC & Stream & StreamSubscription**, see the image below:

[image]

**Inside the Homepage screen:**

```dart
///...Inside Homepage screen level-0
RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Update value in the BLoC'),
    onPressed: () {
         bloc.changeSelectedState(isSel);
    },
),
//...
```

**inside the BLoC:**

```dart
class Bloc {
  final BehaviorSubject<bool> _isSelectedStreamController = BehaviorSubject<bool>();

  // Retrieve data from stream
  Stream<bool> get isSelectedStream => _isSelectedStreamController.stream;

  // Add data to stream
  Function(bool) get changeSelectedState => _isSelectedStreamController.sink.add;

  void dispose() {
    _isSelectedStreamController.close();
  }
}
final bloc = Bloc();
```

**Inside any widget in any level as long as it can reach the bloc:**

```dart
// This inside the two-levels down stateful widget..
StreamSubscription isSelectedSubscription;
Stream isSelectedStream = bloc.isSelectedStream;
isSelectedSubscription = isSelectedStream.listen((value) {
      // Set flag then setState so can show the border.
      setState(() {
        isSelected = value;
      });
});

//...other code

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Container(
      decoration: isSelected
          ? BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 2,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            )
          : null,
          //...other code
    );
}
```

**so the new design of my widget includes the BLoC as a main part of it, see the image:**

[image]

and...works like a charm with flexible and clean code and architecture ^^